# GREP for end of text symbol

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I need to go through and join hundreds of separate text frames into a unified text thread. The problem is that when I link the frames the style of the first paragraph of the frame I'm linking to ofter changes to the style of the last paragraph in the text frame I'm linking from. If I could put a frame break into the end of every text frame I could avoid this problem. The hidden character for 'end of text' looks like a hashtag. Is there a GREP for this?

Just found on the Adobe forums that \z is the character I want, and it does find all the instances, but when I try to change them for page breaks I crash my programme. Every damn time.

Comment: That isn't a character. Better to identify all of the stories whose last character is not an end of paragraph character and add an end of paragraph character to those stories.

Comment: So the Adobe forums said that \z is the character I want, and it does find all the instances, but when I try and change them for page breaks I crash my programme!

Comment: did you see this? https://indesignsecrets.com/topic/end-of-story-symbol-find-and-change

Answer (score 1):

You can't only search for a single location placeholder with InDesign's GREP (it has its wings clipped) – although it should not have made it crash. Change the Keep Settings for every *first* paragraph in your stories to start in a new frame, it'll have the same result when joining.

You can use GREP for this as well. Search for

```
\A.
```

and leave the Change To field blank. In the Change To formatting field, set your new Keep options. `\A` matches Start of Story, and the single `.` is so you actually can find a (any) character so it won't crash on you again.

Answer (score 1):

So I did this in the end which achieved what I wanted:

Find: (.)(\z)

Change to: $1~R

This way when I linked the text frames the styles didn't get changed.

Thanks for everyone's help, esp. user1754036 for the link to InDesign Secrets which really solved the puzzle for me.